# Calculating time to disk full for n processes downloading to available storage

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

I am working out a puzzle given by office leads to work out a solution.

The puzzle is:

> n number of processes are running on the computer. They run forever, never die, and no new processes get spawned. Each process takes memory at a constant, individual rate - process p_i (with 0 <= i < n) consumes 1 byte after every d(p_i) seconds. The total amount of available disk space is denoted by X.
>
> Calculate the time to fill up available storage in seconds.

The bare logic I have written below doesn't seem to be correct solution; I am little confused by process with different rate at which disk can get full.

```
number_of_processes = 3
available_storage = 6 # in bytes
write_speed_x = 1 #(byte/ p_i second)
write_speed_y = 3
write_speed_z = 2
timeTaken = 0

pr_i = [write_speed_x, write_speed_y, write_speed_z]

for i in pr_i:
    timeTaken += available_storage/i


print timeTaken
```

Comment: "Memory" usually refers to RAM while "storage" refers to disk or other non-volatile but typically slower media. You seem to be confusing or conflating the two.

Comment: each process takes constant memory refers to constant disk space in the available storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you wrongly understand memory consumption definition. Every process (with index `i`) eats one byte more every `d[i]` seconds, so it consumes `k` bytes after `k*d[i]` seconds. We can say that speed of memory consumption is `1/d[i] bytes/second` on the long time interval, but memory consumption rise is discrete.

```
time     0   di   2di   3di
mem      0    1    2     3
```

For example three processes with `d = [1,3,2]` seconds/byte memory consumption depends on time as:

```
 process  p0   p1  p2  overall
 time
 0         0   0   0   0
 1         1   0   0   1 
 2         2   0   1   3 
 3         3   1   1   5
 4         4   1   2   7  
 5         5   1   2   8  
 6         6   2   3   11
```

Memory occupied by every process rises step-by-step, but these steps arise on different moments of time (imagine stairs with uneven steps).

We can calculate memory consumption for any moment t - just sum memory for all processes

```
OverallMem(t) = t//d[0] + t//d[1] + t//[d[2]+...
```

where `//` is integer division (`div`, `floor(t/d[i])`)

Simple way: calculate memory consumption using formula above for `t=1, t=2, t=3...` and so on until it exceeds X. Works for small X but slow for large X. Python 3 example:

```
def timetodie(lst, x):
    mem = 0
    t = 0
    while (mem < x):
        t += 1
        mem = sum(t//v for v in lst)
              #mem = 0
              #for v in lst:
                   #mem += t // v
    return t

print(timetodie([1,3,2], 6))
print(timetodie([2,5,7], 11))
>>4
>>14
```

Because memory consumption is non-decreasing, we can apply **binary search** approach to find moment `t` when `OverallMem(t)` becomes larger than `X`.

Starting conditions:
left border for binary search is 0
rought right border is `X * Min(d[i])`

More optimal left border proposed by @AJNeufeld: `X//sum(1/v for v in lst)`.
Perhaps in this form: `math.floor(x / sum(1/v for v in lst))`

I hope that this clue is enough to elaborate solution

Comment: Hi @MBo, I didn't get you, so at T = 1s, memory consumption will be 6 bytes, right, at T=2, Total memory consumption will be 12 bytes and so on...correct ?

Comment: i was after total time taken to completely fill up X memory !

Comment: No. Think about `consumes 1 byte after every d(p_i) seconds`. Memory for [1,3,2] depending on time: `0+0+0, 1+0+0, 2+0+1, 3+1+1, 4+1+2 etc`

Comment: I gave more detailed example in answer body

Comment: Umiesz pisać python

Comment: @Ciasto piekarz To start, implement linear approach (I just added "simple way")

Comment: @MBo using linear search I got 11 as overall shown in opening post for loop time taken..

Comment: Look at my table - you should find 4 as time to reach X=6

Comment: `while mem < x:
        t += 1
        mem = sum(t//v for v in lst)` takes good amount of time  for long list of process.

Comment: Of course, this is straightforward method. And I've proposed faster approach.

Comment: 0 is a sub-optimal left border for your search.  A more optimal one would be `X//sum(1/v for v in lst)`.